# The binary version of its metadata is 1.0.1, expected version is 1.1.0

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

In intellij idea 16 EAP 144.3357.4 I have a pure Kotlin cmd project currently refusing to run with this error:

```
The binary version of its metadata is 1.0.1, expected version is 1.1.0
```

The project runs on the command-line - I invalidated caches and restarted Idea - nothing helped. Anyone had the same problem and found a way to get it working?

Comment: by what process did you invalidate caches? i'm intrigued! i have never done this and sounds mysterious. [ctrl-shift-A "invalidate"]==mind_blown!!!

Comment: this is an action in idea - often helps solving problems - but not this one ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be mismatch between the kotlin library used in your project and the version of the plugin are not compatible.

Check the Kotlin plugin version and you'll most likely see something similar to:

> Version: 1.0.0-rc-1007-IJ143-11

Then check the version of the Kotlin libraries by looking into `META-INF/build.txt` or `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and it'll most likely be other version like `1.0.0-beta-4589`.

To resolve the problem update Kotlin libraries to version `1.0.0-rc-1007` which can be found in this maven repository: https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap.

Kotlin compiler marks each `.class` with [`@kotlin.Metadata`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/Metadata.kt) to indicate, among others:

> The version of the bytecode interface (naming conventions, signatures) of the class file annotated with this annotation.

That is how the compiler detected incompatibilities.

Comment: Spot on! Just to note to @ligi that 1025 is the latest EAP Kotlin build.

Comment: To update the plugin to a later EAP, the Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates needs to be set to EAP releases, otherwise you will be stuck at the installed version until the next public release.  Intellij IDEA 16 EAP seems to have updated to include Kotlin EAP silently.

Comment: What if we want to downgrade kotlin version, this comes very handy for Android Studio upgrade issues...