# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, stripe-payments

In [Stripe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripe_(company)), my client wants email and cardholder name, but the Stripe payment UI doesn't provide that option in `com.stripe.android.view.CardMultilineWidget`. I wanted to give it a try with the latest stripe version,

1. I was using Stripe version (14.1.1). So I updated it to the latest one (16.8.0)
2. The build showed me the error that it doesn't take `minSdkVersion 19`. It requires `21` in `manifest merger`. So I updated `minSdkVersion` to `21`.
3. I got

   ```
   caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/4541b0189187e0017d23bbb0afebd16a/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
   ```

I tried changing the Gradle version, but I am still getting the same error. How can I solve the incompatible error and add the email and cardholder name in Stripe?

Comment: Regarding the Kotlin build error, do either of these previous answers help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67470309 https://stackoverflow.com/a/35170452

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448034/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version)

Comment: I experienced this issue while building an app that used my library. It appeared to be caused by an update of the Kotlin Gradle plugin from 1.4.32 to 1.5.31. To fix this, I changed the languageVersion and apiVersion to '1.4' and built a new version of the library. Not directly related to the client issue described here, but possibly useful for library maintainers.

Answer (score 531, accepted):

Changing this in file `build.gradle` solved my problem.

From

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

Or whatever the latest version of Kotlin [available](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details) and make sure to update Kotlin version on Android Studio as well.

Comment: This line of code is in this file: "flutter_app/android/build.gradle"

Comment: minSdkVersion 24

Comment: For a detailed explanation of what is happening here see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425347/114549

Comment: It's not good to set the latest version as it may not be compatible with your current version of gradle. Versions of gradle and kotlin must macth to avoid issues as detailed here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/compose-compatibility-and-versioning.html#kotlin-compatibility

Answer (score 271):

### Although this question has been answered, I think it's worth explaining what is happening

For the example:

```
The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

The `expected` version is the Kotlin for `kotlin-gradle-plugin`

The `binary` version is the what is downloaded (or previously compiled)
for `com.android.tools.build:gradle`

**<project_dir>/android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20' // <= expected version is 1.5.1
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1' // downloads 1.7.1 Metadata
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // <= 1.5.20 used here
```

### Why is this Happening So Much?

1. The user updates the Kotlin version of the plugin to match the IDE version per the warning.

[image: Warning from Android Studio to match Kotlin Versions]

2. The user updates the android build tools gradle plugin per the warning

[image: Warning about android build tools]

***This is the WRONG version!***

Now you don't have any warnings, but the version suggested is `7.1.3` which is not the latest. (I don't know why it suggests this older version) `7.3.1` is currently the latest and is meta data `1.7.1`, so it will match the Kotlin version of `1.7.20` (which is also metadata `1.7.1`)

### What else could be wrong?

Due to caching, gradle may be using an older dependency before you updated. To start clean:

1. delete the ~/.gradle/cache directory
2. delete the android/.gradle directory
3. delete the project_dir/build dir
4. ensure the `android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properies` has the correct `distributionUrl` (currently `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip`)
5. from project_dir do `flutter build apk`

NOTE: your dependencies may need to be updated if their `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version is too old. Alternatively, both the kotlin and `tools:gradle` versions can be downgraded to compatible version that match metadata (although Android Studio will warn for that not matching the IDE Kotlin version)

### How to Prevent this from happening Again?

- Use the same Kotlin version as the IDE normally for `ext.kotlin_version`. see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details
- Double check the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version. See https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google

Comment: should be the accepted answer, best answer here

Comment: ensuring the version and checking the list urls for the correct versions did the trick. was on 1.5.30 for some reason instead of 1.7.2

Comment: How about that? This IS the CORRECT ANSWER. Thanks guy!!

Comment: So, it is a version checking issue of AGP. AGP should validate the kotlin version the project current using is whether compatible or not.

Comment: I was also getting this issue in case of Google Captcha V3 SDK integration below solution work for me 

ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.20"
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

Comment: Actually we also need to consider which dependency failing this, in my case I need to lower down the version of that particular dependency.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to update the build gradle, here is the fastest way I could find https://stackoverflow.com/a/72984766/4943676 . When opening Android Studio, i had to do "flutter clean" first and then build and finally update. I also had to do this operation twice to get the latest version. If this helped, please give a thumbs up to that guy, he deserves it

Comment: this helped me a lot. I had to open the Android folder in android studio, this made a sync automatically for me.

Comment: How would I find out that gradle:7.3.1 will download version 1.7.1 Metadata?

Comment: I went through all of these steps and the problem remained. For me, the thing that fixed it was using the Android Studio "AGP upgrade assistant". This updated the `build.grade`, `gradle-wrapper.properties` as in this answer. But it also updated `settings.gradle`, which for me was the final thing causing this error.

Comment: It's not enough to check available version, one must match gradle with kotlin as per second tables here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/compose-compatibility-and-versioning.html#kotlin-compatibility

Answer (score 66):

I had this problem in a Flutter project.

In my case, a line for *kotlin-gradle-plugin* was missing in the Android *build.gradle* file, so adding `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'` didn’t fix it.

After adding

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

the error was gone.

Full code section:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

If you are facing this error in Flutter build for Android then try to change the Kotlin version to

`ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'`

[image]

Comment: If 1.4.32 doesn't work try 1.6.0

Comment: How were you using VSCode to build Android apps?

Answer (score 22):

Firstly, go to settings, and then navigate to plugins. Find the Kotlin plugin and update it.

Next, in gradle files, go to *build.gradle* (Project: YourApp). Then, change the following code (in buildscript) from:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

to the latest version, such as:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
```

To know the latest version, go to settings and the plugins, find the Kotlin plugin, and make sure it is updated. The latest version is under JetBrains.

After following the instructions, your error will be resolved.

Comment: My current project is very old. And exactly 1.4.32 version allowed me solve the issue. Updating to newer versions produce some problems.

Comment: Better, see what they recommend here: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that the Kotlin version of your IDE is the same as the version declared in your gradle.build file.

Comment: This is not necessary. The IDE should be backwards compatible with all kotlin versions

Answer (score 16):

It was fixed by updating the Kotlin Gradle plugin version.

In the project level *build.gradle* file, update the following line.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

You can find the latest Kotlin Gradle plugin version at
*[Tools / Build tools / Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html)*.

Answer (score 15):

Changed the Project build gradle to

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In such case, read the build.gradle (:project) carefully. I overlooked the warning that's why I was getting this problem.

Initially my settings of build.gradle (:project) was

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

As I was getting this error

> Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

So I changed this setting in the build.gradle (:project) to the following:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 11):

in my case for

> The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1

got to (dependencies) inside build.gradle(project) convert from `1.5.x` (x) in my case is (20)

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"
```

to `1.7.10`

```
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
```

Answer (score 9):

What do you need to to solve this?

I was facing this issue since last night. Just navigate through some webpages couldn't get to the exact solution. I finally solved it by these steps:

- Replace `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'` with `ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'` in the *build.gradle* file.
- *Clean project* → *Build the project with Gradle files* → *Run*

Answer (score 6):

Go to the file build.gradle, change the version of kotlin.
In case in my flutter project I opened build.gradle and changed

```
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.30'`
```

to
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'`

Here

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    
}
```

}

---

Then save and do

`flutter clean` and `flutter run`.

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

go to `Build.gradle` (Project : NAME_PROJECT) and
set code `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false` in plugins
""" clear any code out of plugin """

Comment: This is the only way to let it works on gradle lately for my case. Thank you!

Comment: I also thank you for reading my message!
I hope you always succeed in programming

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to downgrade `androidx.core:core-ktx` library to any compatible version. This one worked for `kotlin_version = '1.3.31'`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'  // The only working for this version (sdk/gradle)
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2' // The only working for this version (sdk/gradle)
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2' // higher versions require min-sdk >= 26
    ...
}
```

Android SDK: `compileSdkVersion 30` and `minSdkVersion 19`.

Gradle build Tool: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1`.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to file *build.gradle* (Project: yourProjectName).

**Change**

```
plugins {
  ...

  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.x' apply false

  ...
}
```

(1.5.x means x version number at your case, such as 1.5.1.)

**To**

```
plugins {
  ...

  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false

  ...
}
```

It works in my case...

Answer (score 4):

For macOS you can

```
rm -r $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

or you can invalidate caches

```
File >> Invalidate caches
```

Comment: Invalidate cache did it for me

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there might be a vast variety of reasons of this fault. In my case, when I even did not use Kotlin but Java, the problem was I updated Firebase library version to the newest one. I switched from:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.2'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.5.0'
```

an it caused analogous fault. I switched back to the old version and it worked.

"Funny" fact was that fault popped out only when I build apk file. When I build aab for Google Play everything went smooth.

Just for information for others who will check this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers here seem to revolve around projects that use Gradle.

I randomly encountered this problem in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) that that was compiling and running a Maven project just fine 5 minutes before - no configuration changes. I introduced a new exception class and this problem popped up.

I tried invalidating caches and restarting, which didn't resolve the issue - however, disabling and re-enabling the Kotlin plugin resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using Flutter, it was fixed by:

- Updating Android Studio packages, specially the Kotlin plugin.
- Get the last Kotlin plugin version Nbr from [Gradle - Plugin and versions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions). For now it's 1.6.10.
- Update *<Your_project_name_folder>\android\build.gradle* file by replacing the old Kotlin version by the new one you got from the web site above.

  `ext.kotlin_version = '<The_new_version_Nbr>'` *in my case `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'`*
- Restart Visual Studio Code.

You're done.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin config is a nightmare, I have two project, a 100% Java and other with Kotlin, wow, is a huge difference. (And I don't talk about Flutter, it is a similar nightmare). Well, many noise with that. At least for me worked the next steps:

1. running the suggested Kotlin migrations from the IDE
2. invalidate caches

And I added the **kotlin-bom** like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}
```

in the main *build.gradle* file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

And also update the target to:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 34
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: At least you can wake up from a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

Many times, the error can arise after a library integration. The integrated library may be compiled using a Kotlin version newer than the one used in your project. In that case, there can be two solutions:

1. Downgrade the library dependency version.
2. Upgrade the Kotlin version for your own project to be greater than or equal to the library's Kotlin version.

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution for flutter 3 :

Edit this line to set your kotlin to latest version :

id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "**1.9.22**" apply false

in file : project/android/settings.gradle.

The latest koltin version can be find here : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

Answer (score 0):

I have the set minsdk 24 and restart the Android Studio, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VktCG.png) 
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you Kotlin version is compatible with compose version.
if not, then please make the changes and it should work fine.

Compose Compiler Version    Compatible Kotlin Compiler Version

```
1.3.0 --> 1.7.10
1.3.0-rc01 --> 1.7.10
1.3.0-beta01 --> 1.7.10
1.2.0 --> 1.7.0
1.2.0-rc01 --> 1.6.21
1.2.0-beta03 --> 1.6.21
1.2.0-alpha08 --> 1.6.20
1.1.0 --> 1.6.10
1.1.1 --> 1.6.10
1.1.0-rc031.6.10
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply download the updated version.

[image]

I'm currently using macmini with m1 chip.

Before, the version of my android studio was bumble-bee. Now I've updated to version Giraffe.

Everything works fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone tried changing "environment" setting inside pubspec.yaml? because It worked for me. I just copied one of my recently created projects "environment" setting to my older project.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it was a change in an update to **Auth0**. In `build.gradle` we were using a prefix version range:

`implementation 'com.auth0.android:auth0:2.+'`

Since we are overriding the Kotlin version, we just needed to update the **Auth0** version to an exact version to prevent the 6K+ build errors:

`implementation 'com.auth0.android:auth0:2.10.1'`

Answer (score 0):

If this happens on intelliJ go to `preferences --> search for kotlin compiler -->  update kotlin compiler version to 1.1.15`

Answer (score 0):

For me the trick was to update the android library version as well along with kotlin version

**Before**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.0' apply false
```

}

**After**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
```

}

Answer (score 0):

#### Straightforward answer

You need to make sure compose_version, compose_compiler and gradle distribution url as well as Kotlin version are ALL compatible.

It is just a big headache because you need to check the following websites:

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#kts
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material

---

### Step by step to make it work with most recent versions from March 2024:

`flutter clean` (and also trash content of `.gradle/caches` potentially)

Copy/paste the following inside `android` folder (make a backup, don't blame me if things don't go accordingly):

settings.gradle (don't forget to replace `android { namespace` with your package)

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "my.package.appname"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion


    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }


    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler
    }
    dependencies {
        // stable 1.2.1 releases
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
        //...
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "stack.technology.mymap"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

}
```

gradle/wrapper/graddle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip
```

android/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22' // Change here
    ext {
        compose_compiler = '1.5.10'
        compose_version = '1.6.3'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "stack.technology.mymap"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler
    }

    dependencies {
        // stable 1.2.1 releases
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
        //...
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "stack.technology.mymap"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
}
```

How it should work smoothly, as of March 2024.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a cryptic reason. It was running out of memory during build, yet wouldn't be explicit about it, instead throwing the exception about incompatible version of Kotlin.

For me, the solution was to change
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m` to
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m`
in `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 0):

I was using  1.92.22 in  build gradle

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'

in setting.gradle it was  1.7.2 in plugin
when i correct this it work

Answer (score 0):

A lot of answers that are not quite helpful. Setting this or that version does not help as Kotlin-AGP-Android Studio must all be using compatible versions.

A good start is the second table on this page:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/compose-compatibility-and-versioning.html#kotlin-compatibility

Then you need to be sure your version of Android Studio is compatible with the gradle version you want to use which can be found here:

https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin

If you're still having issues, try to clean all cache folders:

- ~/.gradle/cache
- ~/.gradle/caches
- <project_dir>/build
- /.gradle

Answer (score -2):

I have faced this error in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) with a Maven project.
The solution is about to turn off Kotlin plugin in IntelliJ IDEA if you are not using Kotlin in your project.

Go to:

Menu *File* → *Settings* → *Plugins*

And turn off the Kotlin plugin by click on the checkbox. See here:

[image]

Comment: I was working on a Java project that reported the error. This step resolved it for me.

Comment: @IcedDante Glad to hear. Yes , this solutions works if you are not using Kotlin.

Comment: Do not try this now.... Now I've to reinstall android studio
Missing essential plugins:

  com.android.tools.design
  org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch.

Comment: @mr.volatile This solution is applicable for Intellij idea. I have mentioned it in my answer as well (if you’re not using kotlin)

Answer (score -2):

I upgraded the android studio version to the latest and that resolved the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

In my case I was doing:

`implementation("[depName]")`

Instead of:

`implementation "[depName]"`

So basically I was trying to use kotlin instead groovy