# Audio packages flutter checkDebugDuplicateClasses error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Each time i try to use Audio Package as assets_audio_player and audioplayers i get this error
[image]
If i remove the package it works fine and i tried other non audio packages as english words
I need to use audio package in flutter app

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by update kotlin version in android studio, It didn't work at first cause i was having the last stable version of kotlin to my android studio so you may be need to update android studio first
[Solution from related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67832028/execution-failed-for-task-audioplayerscompiledebugkotlin?fbclid=IwAR24F9qbVpNhytO4alicZPDT7Nr6ZDdSD6IU-lW8nAXHyVTnMxnDRhILXWQ)