# Blank White Screen after adding Firebase to flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

After i add Firebase to my flutter project both android and IOS app not working .  here is the error ,

Note-IOS does installing the app , but shows only white blank screen

**Android**

```
e: /Users/capt.nizam/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/00446b2c2a7eae3f618598721af19725/jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-20.0.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.firebase.firebase_analytics_ktx_granule.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

**And IOS APP**

```
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61461/6M_23sVQpSg=/ws
```

Syncing files to device iPhone 13 Pro Max...
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:121:86)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:146:36)
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
#3      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:342:41)
#4      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:31:37)
#5      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:13)
#6      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:42:47)
#7      main (package:ipqb/main.dart:7:18)
#8      _runMainZoned.. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:25)
#9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.d<…>

I followed everything in the docs. i tried multiple time , even checked in a new project i am facing same error !

Comment: Hi Mohammed, Your exception stack will be easier for others to read if you put it in a `code` section.  Is the error happening during the build, test, packaging, or deployment phase?  Does the error explanation in the stack dump make any sense: `Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value`?  Is the source of the exception in your code or in a third-party library?  Hope these questions help get you closer to finding the cause.  Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o)

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is to ensure that when initializing firebase in your project, ensure you include the "name" parameter of your project. See the example below.

```
Future<void> main() async {


WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'firebase-project-name',
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Followed the doc here https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios and it was just showing a blank screen without the name... Thanks Stan !

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that before running your app you have taken the following measures on your IDEs' terminal

1. firebase login -> then provide credentials to log in to your firebase account.
2. flutterfire configure -> this will bring you a list of your firebase apps  then choose the one you linked to your project.
3. follow the ongoing steps (provided to you on your terminal) till you're done.
4. add the code below to your main.dart.

```
  Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  }
```

5. run your app