# React Native webview Gives react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

btroot@btroot-Inspiron-3647:~/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
32 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 30 up-to-date
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5d5c005847cf8de15717b495cdeb2994/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9eb741457c5f4bb9aab62f33b4784f6e/transformed/jetified-react-native-0.69.1-debug-api.jar!/META-INF/ReactAndroid_debug.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f9029077105ee094cb660a998bc51080/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fef35b89e5e15dc545425cdee6369ba0/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewPackage.kt: (8, 77): Unresolved reference: listOf
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewPackage.kt: (12, 76): Unresolved reference: listOf
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopHttpErrorEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopLoadingErrorEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopLoadingFinishEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopLoadingProgressEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopLoadingStartEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopMessageEvent.kt: (22, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopRenderProcessGoneEvent.kt: (24, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent.kt: (16, 11): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent.kt: (18, 11): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent.kt: (28, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5d5c005847cf8de15717b495cdeb2994/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9eb741457c5f4bb9aab62f33b4784f6e/transformed/jetified-react-native-0.69.1-debug-api.jar!/META-INF/ReactAndroid_debug.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f9029077105ee094cb660a998bc51080/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fef35b89e5e15dc545425cdee6369ba0/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewPackage.kt: (8, 77): Unresolved reference: listOf
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewPackage.kt: (12, 76): Unresolved reference: listOf
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopHttpErrorEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopLoadingErrorEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopLoadingFinishEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopLoadingProgressEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopLoadingStartEvent.kt: (23, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopMessageEvent.kt: (22, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopRenderProcessGoneEvent.kt: (24, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent.kt: (16, 11): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent.kt: (18, 11): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/events/TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent.kt: (28, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /home/btroot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b4bd8b2d8b84f89e1b1eb3315da16eb4/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

```
at makeError (/home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/home/btroot/Backup/Rampraveen/React-Native/Experiment/Process/newPaypal/paypal/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).