# "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin." - the case with "build.gradle.kts" file

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ IDEA plugin based on official [Kotlin template](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template). I had no Kotlin experience until tried to develop the plugin for IntelliJ IDEA.

I got the error:

```
C:/Users/I/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/2022.2/42c296374014a649785bb84aa6d8dc2d18f2ca0e/ideaIC-2022.2/lib/3rd-party-rt.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-datetime.kotlin_module: 
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

when updated some options in **gradle.properties**:

```
pluginGroup = com.yamatodaiwa
pluginName = Yamato-Daiwa Frontend
pluginVersion = 0.0.3

pluginSinceBuild = 221
pluginUntilBuild = 222.*

pluginVerifierIdeVersions = 2022.1, 2022.2

platformType = IC
platformVersion = 2022.2
platformDownloadSources = true


javaVersion = 11

gradleVersion = 7.2


kotlin.stdlib.default.dependency = false
```

I checked the [similar topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o), but the solutions like

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

are not actual for the projects with **build.gradle.kts** (not **build.gradle**) - there is no **ext.kotlin_version** option:

```
import org.jetbrains.changelog.markdownToHTML
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

fun properties(key: String) = project.findProperty(key).toString()

plugins {
    // Java support
    id("java")
    // Kotlin support
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.30"
    // Gradle IntelliJ Plugin
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.1.6"
    // Gradle Changelog Plugin
    id("org.jetbrains.changelog") version "1.3.0"
    // Gradle Qodana Plugin
    id("org.jetbrains.qodana") version "0.1.12"
}

group = properties("pluginGroup")
version = properties("pluginVersion")

...
```

[Full code](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-Frontend/blob/master/IDEsPlugins/IntelliJ_IDEA/build.gradle.kts)

If you need to check ano other files to answer, please check the [plugin's repository](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-Frontend/tree/master/IDEsPlugins/IntelliJ_IDEA).

Comment: Try to update the Kotlin Gradle plugin version from 1.5.30 to 1.7.10.

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov, Thank you for the answer. I tried and unfortunately got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.openapi.util.SystemInfoRt`.

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292389/build-plugin-for-20221-error, try to upgrade the Gradle IntelliJ Plugin to 1.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: upgrade all the used Gradle plugins to their latest versions.