# Room and Jetpack Compose may cause this error, "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin."

Tags: android, kotlin

As I introduced Jetpack Compose and Room simultaneously for a new app, my Android Studio threw this error.

```
/***/***/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.0/51736992f422993a1e741051bdf3c12801bc1ca1/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

When I wrote codes without Room libraries, I didn't get the error.
Here is what I tried to solve this problem.

1. Upgrading Android Studio and Kotlin version
2. Referred this page: [Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o)

   However, I wasn't able to find "ext.kotlin_version = 'xxx'.", so I wrote this code in build.gradle, but wasn't able to solve it.

   ```
    buildscript {
       ext {
           compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
           kotlin_version = '1.7.0' // add this line with '1.7.0' and '1.7.1'
       }
   }
   ```
3. Referred another page: https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/issues/1303

How should I do next to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try upgrading **kotlin** to **1.7.10** and **compose** to **1.3.0.**
If not worked,try with **compose** 1.2.0 and **kotlin** 1.7.0
You can find all compataible versions [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#pre-release_kotlin_compatibility).

[image]

Also make sure to use same variable for kotlin gradle plugin in project build.gradle.

> ```
>    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
> ```