# The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1. How to Solve?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle

I connected firebase and I got this error, how can I fix it? (Class 'com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.AuthKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.)

### build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently i had same issue,

I fixed with below steps.

**Project Gradle**

```
 classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10' 
 or 
 id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
```

**App gradle**

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.10"
```

You can find more details on the below thread.
[Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699823/9909365)

Comment: Changing to 1.7.10 returns the error see the logs

Comment: @TriangleN which firebase versions you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It works.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.7.1 not working 1.7.2 working thx

Answer (score 1):

Because of the Kotlin version of your Gradle project. Gradle forces and old version of Kotlin. So the solution is:

**Firstly**, you need to update your Kotlin plugin in Android Studio to the latest version.

**Second**, go to /android/build.gradle and use this code below (note: if the latest kotlin version is greater than > 1.7.20, you need to change 1.7.20 to x.x.x ( x.x.x is the latest Kotlin version ) ).

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this help you in some sort of way.
I have encountered the same exact issue even the GPT failed to help me out, The accepted answer might work for you but it didn't for me what worked was a set of steps:

1. Update the Android studio if not already and update **suspected dependencies** in
   ***build.gradle(app)*** after that
   add `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` if not already
   available .
2. In project Structure make sure you have compatible (Gradle Plugin version,
   Gradle version and Gradle JDK mine were 7.0.2,7.2 and 11 ).
3. In ***Gradle.Properties*** add
   `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true android.enableAapt2=true android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=false org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
4. In ***build.gradle(project)-> allprojects->repositories***
   add
   `configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0" }`
5. Make sure you have same version of kotlin in both build.gradles e.g:
   `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` in **build.gradle(project)->dependencies**
   and `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"` in **build.gradle(app) ->dependencies**
   where
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0' in  **build.gradle(project)->buildscript**

Answer (score -1):

Try downgrading kotlin version from 1.7.1 to 1.5.1. Your current version is causing the issue as firebase auth dependency is not compatible with your current kotlin version.