# Flutter: Android Apk build problem with incompatible Kotlin version

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I need to make a build of my flutter app and share it on firebase app distribution. what happens is that my app build with warnings but in the end the build is ok. But the testers with whom I share the application, manage to download my application but cannot open it.

### This is what is displayed in the console :

```
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
    C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
e: C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.5.0/857678d6b4ca7b28571ef7935c668bdb57e15027/annotation-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
    C:/Users/AbdoulayeB/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          504,3s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (17.4MB).
```

Comment: This could help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o

Answer (score 0):

You should update classpath gradle version in android/build.gradle
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x") maybe update a more recent version (3.0 > 4.0) and try again, this solve my problem. good luck!