# module was compiled with an incompatible version of kotlin. the binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6

Tags: flutter, kotlin, binary, version, metadata

i am getting this problem in buidling the release apk for my futter app , i have tried changing to almost every version of kotlin. can anyone please help me with this problem
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDrwj.png)

i have tried changing to almost every version of kotlin,

here is my android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }


android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.rewaytech.rewayusers"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

and here is my android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425347/14120486).

Right to the point he explains in detail what's going on under the hood!

Comment: thank you so much , my issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Change the version from the one you have the one you need.
This line is in build.gradle

from:

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '>--1.6.1<--' apply false
```

to:

```
 id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
```

Answer (score -1):

I have updated gradle tools and plugin version and that resolved the issue.
For reference this is what I have used.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10'
    }
```

**ItzDavi** posted a detailed answer that is almost the same as mine.