# Flutter - Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I am trying to build my Flutter application which I work on in Android Studio and I get the following error.

```
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/444158a5a1a4ac8afe9995117e41cb16/transformed/jetified-activity-1.7.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/96e72aa9eba981daa2622d9cddde23a6/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/11f9be4c8aaa5d617a7cc1ff1672b6c0/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7ca6a80d16b19d6ba21adc9e99e0a094/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d4006b5d1fcd84b1354bccc2a4c2c3b3/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ec9c5c926719529ab2408cb95b7aa427/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/19827b4a5aaa9813188135a9c7d867bd/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/943f3ada3ec6ed557111efe6a04b12b5/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.1/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.1.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2e721f1bf4bd80f56fac75a967298751/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Omer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.9.0/cd65c21cfd1eec4d44ef09f9f52b6d9f8a720636/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

This is my current buildscript in the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
```

I checked [Kotlin's release details](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#ide-support) for the versions.
I also updated all the dependencies to the latest version.

I tried multiple answers on StackOverflow and GitHub including these:
[Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o#answer-74425347)
[The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0. Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75256812/the-binary-version-of-its-metadata-is-1-8-0-expected-version-is-1-6-0-module-w)
[module was compiled with an incompatible version of kotlin. the binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76634426/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o)
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/130412

I tried to clean and rebuild (`flutter clean` and then `flutter build apk`).
I tried to invalidate caches.
I tried different versions in `ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'`, including the expected version the error mention (1.6.0).

I also tried adding these lines to my `build.gralde` file.

```
ext.kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = '1.4.0'
ext.compose_version = '1.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Gradle to 7.4.2 did the trick for me.

Change

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'

To

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'

Or Open the android code in Android Studio. Android Studio will ask you whether you want to upgrade Gradle. Then proceed with the selected upgrade.