# The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1

Tags: flutter, kotlin

i'm trying to release a flutter app and i get this error if any one have some idea to fix this problem

```
e: /home/muhdroid/Documents/Projects Education/abd_el_wahab_hegazy/build/in_app_update/.transforms/44939e9527cbf0759b903aa9f64015de/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/in_app_update_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/Documents/Projects Education/abd_el_wahab_hegazy/build/screen_brightness_android/.transforms/1e8fa44b7ebdc12cb8742c012a2b08c4/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/screen_brightness_android_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/Documents/Projects Education/abd_el_wahab_hegazy/build/wakelock_plus/.transforms/f6dd81657896465a3658863068a12742/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/wakelock_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/Documents/Projects Education/abd_el_wahab_hegazy/build/volume_controller/.transforms/62b41e1f923cc855df2d35320ec5f6f3/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/volume_controller_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/Documents/Projects Education/abd_el_wahab_hegazy/build/package_info_plus/.transforms/9c9d2fad3b50b2bd23b3490a45f5d32f/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/package_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/Documents/Projects Education/abd_el_wahab_hegazy/build/device_info_plus/.transforms/ccd2969d2b3501b88662c7ce2707f464/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/device_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/abb0272b3c6600cd73455647d3d73261/transformed/jetified-activity-1.7.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a5acbf2c50e89562ee6b04491c773b80/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2b71c9bf05dde48913d902212b8ef681/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d2bd0f9435a9f516bd463d5c9d4ede4b/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /home/muhdroid/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2e60c8de69dbcbad8db906e51762afa6/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the app working fine in debug the problem just when i want build release version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o will solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Open android/build.gradle file and increase the version of ext.kotlin_version to a compatible version of Kotlin. Can you try these steps in order?

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

TO

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
```

Your build.gradle file may look like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Now hit the command below:

```
flutter clean
```

Now run your app again.

You can also benefit from here: [Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o)

Comment: i try it not work

Comment: I found something like this. Maybe it can help. https://marketbusinessnews.com/solutions-to-the-problem-the-binary-version-of-its-metadata-is-1-7-1-expected-version-is-1-5-1/307985/