# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1. React native error

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I have generated a new react native project version 0.72.6 .I have installed latest android studio version iguana with kotlin version 1.9.0  , gradle version 8.4 ,
And here is the build.gradle:

[image]

At first , I wanted to take a build from project but i got this error:

C:/Users/amir/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4
bin/1w5dpkrfk8irigvoxmyhowfim/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-
1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module
was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary
version of its metadata is 1,9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

I also noticed android gradle plugin version field in project structure is empty and only gradle version is available.

I followed and tried almost every solution mentioned in this post

[Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o#77426163)

, but it didn't work so what should  i do to solve this  error?

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn add @react-native/gradle-plugin
```

update it to the latest verison 0.73.3

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.!! All I just did was i removed the whole project and created a new one (latest version ) and then start the build without changing any code but I change gradle version to the latest version in gradle-wrapper.properties.