# In-compatible version for Kotlin in Flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, build

I have a Flutter project which using the following configuration of Kotlin and Gradle versions

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
    }
}
```

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

and I have the following error when trying to build APK by `flutter build apk`

**Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.**

I tried to update the Kotlin version in android/build.gradle to latest version but same error still exist
Also I have latest java installed on my machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o)