# Flutter build apk error: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: android, flutter

I'm encountering an error while trying to build my Flutter APK using the flutter build apk command. The error message is as follows:

```
e: G:/flutter_projects/packagename/build/audioplayers_android/.transforms/0be983bf9619117f31646126f72f6156/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/audioplayers_android_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: G:/flutter_projects/packagename/build/flutter_localization/.transforms/69889dd16353b81229df2498789bed1d/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/flutter_localization_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: G:/flutter_projects/packagename/build/share_plus/.transforms/229c31e449ca5896a61135f6ddf09e5a/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/share_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/da0d083e1feacf64bc0aef840b6dff22/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f79e8577313f08921a0a7a764b1e63ac/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/708035e39f38c5dd3eb3df3005716fb7/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/67e144d89b3a3c000759652254b99de8/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0a3e272b428ece3ddd7cca0fe4036be7/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.6.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.2/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.2.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d475a39ad3359a3d6c2060a337a40125/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-java-1.0.0-beta05/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices-java_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7ce898a889d693a482ed61be271fd87b/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-1.0.0-beta05/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm/1.7.1/63a0779cf668e2a47d13fda7c3b0c4f8dc7762f4/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-android/1.7.1/c2d86b569f10b7fc7e28d3f50c0eed97897d77a7/kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/pc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           38.4s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (91.0MB).
```

Android build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.package.name"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("locationtofile")
            storePassword "734555542"
            keyAlias "aliaskey"
            keyPassword "734555542"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-all.zip
```

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.3)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++"        
      workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

```
Flutter 3.19.0 • channel stable 
Framework • revision bae5e49bc2 
Engine • revision 04817c99c9
Tools • Dart 3.3.0 • DevTools 2.31.1
```

I tried many solutions and did all the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425347/4045091), but nothing works!

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the packages you are using? Or downgrading your Kotlin version?

Comment: yes, i tried both and the problem always persist.

Comment: @Hossam Might be this answer is your solutions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o/74425347#74425347)