# how to downgrade the kotlin version - after flutter 3 (if I don't use bulidScript )

Tags: flutter, firebase, kotlin

when I installing firebase in my project that it's use flutter 3.19 , I use kotlin version 1.9.0
I did all the steps required to download Firebase, but when executing the project, this error appears

> "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1."

I searched for a solution to the problem and I found it here

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o](https://stackoverflow.com)

But I use flutter, and after the last update, flutter no longer use BuildScript, so I don't know where I can put the old version of Kotlin. In addition to my question, I would like to add, I really don't know why asked for an even older version!!
Is there any help? Thank you

what I am trying to do:

I try to set ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.1"

and I expecte to my app is works

this is my andriod gradle file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually this line `ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.1"` is correct.
But you also have to set the correct gradle `distributionUrl`

For distributionUrl path: **android/gradle/wrapper
/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

Change also gradle classpath in the dependencies bloc on your **build.gradle**

classpath path : **android
/build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
```

**You can find embedded gradle with related embedded kotlin version [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#kotlin)**

**FOR PEOPLE WHO WOULD LIKE TO ADD KOTLIN VERSION WITHOUT BUILDSCRIPT SEE CODE BELOW**

in the `plugins` block

```
plugins {     
   id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false 
}
```

You can find more information about kotlin and gradle version **[here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#apply-the-plugin)** and [**here**](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android/1.9.22).
In Both cases ( with or without BuildScript ) you should check for you gradle version to match with the given kotlin version

Comment: Thank you, but what I am actually suffering from is that I cannot find the place to put this line
" 
ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.1"
"
 in the android/gradle file because after the release of Flutter 3
The BuildScript part has been removed

you can see my post I edit it and add scrrenshot from my android/gradle file

Comment: Ho i see. You should add the line in the `plugins` block like this

`plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}`

I gave you the version **1.8.22** because i guess your gradle version in **android/gradle/wrapper /gradle-wrapper.properties** is **7.5** or higher

But in case you would want to adapt your Kotlin version depending on your gradle version. You can find the info you want [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#apply-the-plugin) and [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android/1.7.10)