Flutter Build Fails with Kotlin Version Conflict and Dependency Issues
I'm working on a Flutter project that integrates several Firebase services and other dependencies. I'm encountering build failures related to Kotlin version conflicts and unresolved dependencies.
e: /Users/[username]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f3ee5d6927169a72accd22ad384cb20c/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/third_party.java_src.protobuf.current.java.com.google.protobuf.kotlin_shared_runtime.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.


Relevant Part of build.gradle (Project-Level):
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

Relevant Part of build.gradle (App-Level):
android {
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "[applicationId]"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        ...
    }
    ...
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0'
}


gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

gradle.properties
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Dependencies
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^3.1.1
  provider: ^6.1.2
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  geolocator: ^12.0.0
  http: ^1.2.1
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^5.0.2
  cloud_functions: ^5.0.2
  timeago: ^3.6.1
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  file_picker: ^8.0.6
  firebase_storage: ^12.1.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.7.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
  loader_overlay: ^4.0.0
  snack: ^2.0.0

Using flutter clean && flutter run

Check this out I think it was the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425347/10423080

Maybe it's a catch issue just hit the clear catch command.
